# How do I remove ads from Cydia?

Tags: cydia

The ads from Cydia are really intrusive and slows down the application a lot. How do I remove them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solutios is to edit `/etc/hosts` file and add:

```
127.0.0.1 pagead2.googlesyndication.com
127.0.0.1 media.fastclick.net
127.0.0.1 cpxinteractive.com
127.0.0.1 adserving.cpxinteractive.com
```

If you know more addresses let me know.

Comment: `ib.adnxs.com` as well.